# Stored Procedure is returning a int value and not the columns

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure written by someone I don't have access to. When I add the stored proc I am getting the definition below telling me I am returning an int value (-1). Why am I returning an int and not rows? When I execute the sp from Visual Studio 2012 Server Explorer it reutrns the appropriate output as shown below. I am using Entity Framework

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994927/stored-procedure-returning-an-int) but I'm not sure how complex is too complex when it says the sp may be to complex.

[image]

[image]
Here is the stored Proc

```
@Start_Date AS DATETIME,
@End_Date AS DATETIME 

AS

SELECT DLY.[GroupName]
    ,SUM(DLY.[Sales]) AS 'Sales'
    --,[Order Date]

FROM


(SELECT NDO.[No_]
      ,NDO.[Item Category]
      ,CAST(NDO.[Amount]-NDO.[Amount VOID] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS 'Sales'
     ,NDO.[Entry Date] AS 'Order Date'
     ,'GroupName'=
     CASE
        WHEN NDO.[No_] = '' THEN('UNKNOWN')
        --WHEN NDO.[Item Category] IS NOT NULL AND [Item Reporting Category Code] IS NULL THEN(NDO.[No_])
        WHEN [Item Reporting Category Code] IS NULL THEN(NDO.[No_])
        ELSE [Item Reporting Category Code]
     END
  --INTO #Sales_Lines
  FROM [Protective LIVE$Net Daily Orders] NDO LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Protective LIVE$Item] I ON NDO.[No_] = I.[No_] ) AS DLY
  WHERE DLY.[Order Date] BETWEEN @Start_Date AND @End_Date
  AND DLY.Sales <> '0'
  --WHERE DLY.Sales <> '0'
  GROUP BY DLY.[GroupName]
```

Comment: How are you adding it to your context?

Comment: Through Entity Frame work. Added that to the question

Comment: notice its got @RETURN_VALUE = 0 in the VS output - is that not your int?

Comment: @ajg It's returning -1

Comment: Are you using Code First?  Show how the stored procedure is setup in your context.

Comment: I'm using Database first

Comment: I found this [article][1] and when I checked the Import function it said it was mapping to the correct fields. I checked my repository and it is now working.


  [1]: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/data-read-using-stored-procedure.aspx